# Why do I get a runtime error when installing a new dependency on a newly cloned project?

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-8

Edit:

1. the error is because a php code, which I wrote inside my project, is executed.
2. this is a query inside my website, there is NO reason for the setup to execute it at all.
3. It's a laravel&composer setup issue, but i can't tell where it is originated and why.
4. In my laravel project I wrote a query that gets categories, the code is executed inside the default laravel native `AppServiceProvider` file/class, inside the `boot()` function.
5. the code CAN'T work before setup is completed since i don't have even the database... there is no reason for the setup to execute it.

I'm trying to install sail into my cloned project. I am using the script from the official documentation:

(note, as shown in the edited section below) that the error is because of this line `$categories = Category::all()->where('active', true);` in the `boot()` function that resides in the `AppProviderService` class.
**I don't understand why the code is executed at all, when installing composer dependencies ...**

```
docker run --rm \
-u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
-v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
-w /var/www/html \
laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

However, it fails with this error:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev) Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform. Nothing to install, update or remove Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from `categories`)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:760
    756▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    757▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    758▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    759▕         catch (Exception $e) {   ➜ 760▕             throw new QueryException(
    761▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    762▕             );
    763▕         }
    764▕     }

  1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider))

      +20 vendor frames   22  app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:33
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::all() Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Commenting the `boot()` function in the `AppServiceProvider` solved it, but what is the fix without commenting code ...

Comment: It can't find the MySQL driver. publish docker-compose.yml and make sure that mysql is in those services

Comment: The problem does not look related to Composer to me, neither to Docker itself. I would assume that you have a problem with the database, as shown in the error message

Answer (score 0):

When executing `install`, composer will execute the `post-install-cmd` scripts.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#installer-events

Your project seems to be misconfigured in some way or another, so when executing the post-install scripts it will fail.

You can either fix the project setup (so it doesn't fail when running `install`) or simply pass `--no-scripts` to `install`, so that these scripts aren't executed.

Be mindful, though, that you may need to run these scripts manually later on, since they may perform some housekeeping chores. Understanding the project and its running stack is usually a good idea.